# Join two Tables with calculated DAX measure inbetween

Tags: powerbi, dax

In my Power BI Report I have two tables "Answers" and "Colors" and a measure "Rank".
Table "Answers":

```
| Animal  | Viewed |
| Cat     | 17     |
| Chicken | 12     |
| Cow     | 7      |
| Dog     | 28     |
| Goat    | 36     |
```

Tabble "Colors":

```
| Color  | Sort |
| Red    | 1    |
| Yellow | 2    |
| Blue   | 3    |
```

My measure "Rank" calculates the **rank of the viewed Animals filtered by a slicer**:

```
Rank = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(Answers)),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(Answers),
        Answers[Viewed] >= MIN(Answers[Viewed])
    )
)
```

So I get this result:

```
| Animal  | Viewed | RANK |
| Chicken | 12     | 2    |
| Cow     | 7      | 3    |
| Dog     | 28     | 1    |
```

Now I would love to link these two tables using the measure like this "Rank = Sort" to get this **final result**:

```
| Animal  | Viewed | Rank | Color  |
| Chicken | 12     | 2    | Yellow |
| Cow     | 7      | 3    | Blue   |
| Dog     | 28     | 1    | Red    |
```

How can I achieve this?
Please let me know.

Comment: `Rank` is a measure, its value changes based on slicer, whereas, relationships ie Joins are evaluated on refresh time. so it's not possible to do so, you can make a work around if you know for certain that `Rank` can't  surpass a certain value.

Comment: One way you *may* be able to do it is to create a calculated column on each of the two tables that uses RANKX. Then you could use INNERJOIN() to return the two derived tables joined on the rank values.

Comment: You can use Lookupvalue function in DAX to add color column

Comment: How would a Lookupvalue measure look for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned the workaround would be a measure to get color based on Rank value:

```
ColorRank = CALCULATE(MAX(Colors[Color]),FILTER(Colors,[Rank] = Colors[Sort]))
```

Comment: Thank you. With this, I can finaly torn off the random colors on charts.